If the sum of two positive measures is regular, then so is each individual.
I'm seeing problem 26 of Folland's real analysis chapter 3. It says if we have two positive mutually singular measures on R^n, such that their sum is regular, then so is each individual. But I believe the mutually singular condition here is redundant. Isn't that true?

Do they have to be Borel measures? Is $\mathbb R^n$ endowed with the standard topology?

@ECL Yes. Borel Measures with the standard topology

can you prove inner regularity without the assumption?
